# How to change the output format of a node-Postgressql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am writing a program that queries a Postgresql database using node.js. I have the correct query coming out of the database. I just have a problem with the format of the output. I need the result to be sent to another function.

I am using Postgresql and nodejs to query a database and my result is coming out as `{ model: 'Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)' }`. I want `Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)` to be the result and to be sent to the `setValue` function.

Should I query the database in a different way as I have other queries to be sent to other functions for calculations?

```
client.connect()
    .then(() => console.log("Connected successfuly"))
    .then(() => client.query("select model from \"aircraftModels\" where model = $1", ["Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)"]))
    .then (results => setValue(results.rows))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
    .finally(() => client.end())

function setValue(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

Actual Result: `{ model: 'Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)' }`

Expected Result: `Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)`

Comment: Then log `value.model` instead of `value`.

Comment: ```value.model``` comes back as undefined

Comment: Then you need to parse the JSON into an object and *then* access `value.model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is coming back as a json string you would do the following.

Parse the string with JSON.parse(value) then you can call .model on it.

```
const value = JSON.parse(value);
console.log(value.model)
```

However it appears that you are already getting a valid javascript object so you should be able to call value.model

It appears that your request however from discussing with you is returning an array, this is because you may have more then one. To read the first result of the database you can do `value[0].model`

Comment: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at setValue 
``` Getting an error

Comment: @jamo1909 sorry after double checking it appears its returning a already valid object. what happens when you log out console.log(value, value.model). It should not come back as undefined are you sure you did not make a typo ?

Comment: ```[ { model: 'Antonov An-148 (241 nmi)' } ] undefined
```

Comment: Ah ! Well there you go my friend it is an array ! if you call value[0].model you will get what you want.

Comment: It is worth noting that, the reason it returns an array is because you may have multiple results come back from the database table.

I will updated my answer accordingly. @jamo1909

Comment: Yes, that correct. It is an array. ```value[0].model``` works . Thank you @Morphasis